Components Filter in Geocoding Request
The following API request
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sedanstra%C3%9Fe+9&components=locality%3ABerlin&region=de&language=de&key=...
yields
{
"results" : [],
"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
despite the address Sedanstraße 9 exists in Berlin, Germany.
I am sure (because I had a JUnit test for that request) that the request worked 2 months ago.
I noticed that other requests change there results, too.
Why does this happen?
The same API requests with different localities 'Frankfurt' or Köln' yield correct results, the API request without any locality yields a result in 'Lüdenscheid'.
Why in Lüdenscheid, and why not a multiple result for all Sedanstraße 9 addresses in Germany?

Normally you'd report issues to the Geocoding API issue tracker, when they can be so easily reproduced.
However this one does not reproduce now, the first result is ChIJFc_py5ZaqEcRhnfXH3Bvks4 which looks like a good result.
